# what is the relationship between Ring and Pedestal - do I need to know Ring to use Pedestal?

Tags: clojure, ring, pedestal

I was led to believe that Pedestal is a replacement for Ring however from all the examples I see that Pedestal actually uses Ring. This is most confusing! Do I need to know and understand how Ring works in order to use Pedestal effectively. In essence, does Pedestal 'stand on the shoulders of Ring' or is it intended to replace it completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [crossclj.info](https://crossclj.info/ns/io.pedestal/pedestal.service/0.4.1/project.clj.html#uses) (search for `ring/`) `ring/core` is a dependency of `pedestal.service` - therefor I'd say to:

> relationship between Ring and Pedestal ?

`ring/core` is a dependency of `io.pedestal/pedestal.service`

---

Specificly it seems to use ring for its `interceptors` and on pedestals' doc it mentions `The ability to utilize Ring Middleware as Pedestal Interceptors`.

Imagine you have some ring handlers already, you can use them as Pedestal Interceptors, but if you do not, you a free to not use them.

(Disclaimer: I neither used Ring nor Pedestal - just perused the doc)

Comment: The link is broken. Here you can see that [io.pedestal/pedestal.service's project.clj](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/3ba98b88b93f1781b9cdbce0670993e9e8856cdf/service/project.clj#L29) declares its dependency on ring/ring-core.